# Click on image in Rspec (Capybara)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have code like this in my spec (the commented lines are another ways I tried):

```
context "when click on player avatar" do
  #before { find('.thumbnail').first.click }
  #before { click_link(@player.id) }
  before { find("##{@player.nickname}").click }

  #before { click_link(@player.nickname) }
  it { print html }
  it { should have_title(@player.full_name.to_s) }
end
```

This is code of my home page (from browser):

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
      <a class="thumbnail" href="/players/7" id="paterson"><img alt="7" src="/system/players/avatars/000/000/007/medium/7.jpg?1438783830" /></a>
      <h2>Pat War</h2>
      <p>Also called @paterson.</p>
    </div>
```

And from html.erb:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 post">
      <%= link_to image_tag(top_player.avatar.url(:medium)), player_path(top_player), class: "thumbnail", id: top_player.nickname %>
      <h2><%= top_player.firstname + " " + top_player.lastname %></h2>
      <p>Also called @<%= top_player.nickname %>.</p>
    </div>
```

And fragment of log from RSpec:

```
  2) Pages Home page when click on player avatar 
     Failure/Error: before { find("##{@player.nickname}").click }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/players/show.html.erb:35:in `_app_views_players_show_html_erb__1032484200_105052510'
     # /home/jasiek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionview-4.1.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
```

In browser app works.

All ways I tried (commented lines in spec) cause the same error.

Comment: Add `/app/views/players/show.html.erb:35:` where the error actually occurs.

Comment: Both `before { find('.thumbnail').first.click }` or `before { click_link('.thumbnail', match: :first) }` will work to click the link but you have an error in your view - not in your spec!

Comment: Thanks! Fixed. I have stupid error in my view but I didn't search in views.